# How does Firebase Sign in with Phone Number prevent abuse with a Disposable Phone Number services

Tags: firebase, mobile, firebase-authentication, fraud-prevention, sms-verification

The idea of authenticating with a phone number seems like a good idea on the surface to prevent users creating multiple accounts. However there are a number of services out there that supply disposable numbers for one time use.

How does Firebase deal with that situation? Is there a best practices solution to this?

We have not set up this type of authentication as we aren't sure this will help.